# Best practice to fetch and send the million of records with JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, database, jdbc, apache-camel, spring-jdbc

In my web application , the user can write their own sql queries and can create dataset.I am using REST component of Apache Camel and Spring JDBC with JdbcTemplate to execute the query. But while executing the query, returning large number of records (around million) the exception is thrown with following stacktrace:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange:...
.....
.....
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Following is the way ,I am using to query the database and send in the response:

REST endpoint

```
rest("/abc").consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
.get("/xyz").to("bean:d?method=getXYZ(${body})").outTypeList(Map.class)
```

Method executing query:

```
public List<Map<String,Object>> getXYZ(Map<String,Object> details) {
JdbcTemplate jdbc=new JdbcTemplate(ds);  //ds is DataSource Object

List<Map<String,Object>> resultSet=jdbc.query(details.get("query").toString(), new RowMapper<Map<String,Object>>() {

                @Override
                public Map<String, Object> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                    DateFormat nice = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
                    for(int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
                        Object o = rs.getObject(i);
                        if(o instanceof Date) {
                            o = nice.format(o);
                        }
                        //put into map.
                        map.put(meta.getColumnLabel(i), o);
                    }
                    return map;
                }

            });
    return resultSet;
   }
```

I tried by setting fetch size with `jdbc.setFetchSize(1000)`  and also tried with increasing the heap memory with `-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` but was not able to sort it out.

What is the best practice to query,fetch and send the response with such a large data?

What is creating the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError ?

Is there any way to compress the data and auto decompress at client side ? or streaming the resultset ?

Comment: You should paginate if the number of record to result is greater thant a certain amount and return some kind of token/curosr, like a lot of public api does (google calendar, youtube, twitter...)

Comment: Does it mean that I should internally modify the query, written by user to create dataset and then make multiple call to REST request by sending updated cursor everytime.

Comment: exactly add limit to them

Answer (score 0):

OutOfMemory is happening because of the large number of objects being loaded into you application.

Lets imagine that only String objects are loaded. Java stores 2 bytes per character, so lets imagine that all Strings that are being loaded are 5 characters long.

Let's create very very approximate calculation. String object of 5 characters is 10 bytes. 1000 of them makes it approximately 10 kilobytes and 1000000 makes it approximately 10 megabytes.

I assume your objects are not just 5 character Strings, so your can imagine how quickly you memory can be spent.

I would strongly suggest that you restrict users to limited number of rows and introduce pagination. So even in user doesn't enter limit and offset in his SQL, I would add the programatically, to avoid this problem.